# How to create a highcharts dot plot graph? - R Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How can I create a highcharts graph like this using the R `highcharter` package?

It is a simple count of sectors (instances) above or bellow 0 and coloured to reflect the value.

This may sometime be termed a dot plot (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html)?

image from (https://graphics.wsj.com/job-market-tracker/)

[image]

Some sample data:

```
data = data.table(
  CJ(date = seq(as.IDate("2019-01-01"), as.IDate("2019-01-10"), by = "day"),
     group = seq(1,20))
)

data[, value := runif(n=200, -5,5)]
```

Comment: Hi. In general, Highcharts does not provide this kind of graph just like that. It can be achieved using the scatter series, but with some customizations (in JavaScript). It will be even harder to adapt those customizations to R. Unfortunately, it goes far beyond the standard Highcharts scope of support, but if you have further questions, you can contact Highcharts Support Team by support@highcharts.com

Comment: this is true, I have managed a bit

Comment: @raf18seb is there any way to get it to show the different **group**s as different series? on the chart? (please see my attempt at an answer)

Answer (score 2):

This is as far as I got:

```
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

data = data.table(
  CJ(date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-02-10"), by = "day"),
     group = seq(1,20))
)

# generate random value
data[, value := round(runif(n=dim(data)[1], -5,5),4)]

# categorize it from 1 to 10
data[, cat:=cut(value, breaks=quantile(data[value!=0]$value, seq(0,1,0.1)), labels=seq(1,10))]

# assign colour based on value
colf = colorRampPalette(colors = c("red","yellow", "green"))
cols = colf(10)
data[, color := as.factor(cols[cat])]

# generate x and y
data[, x := datetime_to_timestamp(date)]
data[, y := order(order(value))-sum(value<0), date]

data[, name := group]

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "scatter") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "Performance = <b>{point.value}</b> <br> Group = <b>{point.name}</b>") %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat(chart = list(backgroundColor = "#FFF"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, groupPadding=0)
```

[image]

It also works with more points:
[image]

Comment: This is really interesting. I used your code to recreate the WSJ chart to great effect...until I had more than a few dozen time slices - at which point all the dots became orange in the graph but the tooltip maintained the assigned color value.

Comment: sounds like a strange highchart issue, could it be because too many points are being displayed and it cant handle it? I managed to get it working with over 2,000 points (see answer).

Comment: Yes, I suspect it is a highcharts (or highcharter) issue. I am using highcharter v0.7.0.9000. This is definitely an interesting way to present LMI data.