# R Highcharts how to do a stacked dotplot

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I wrote this ggplot code:

```
`ggplot(dt, aes(x = 1, y = yearValueDecimal)) + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='up',stackratio=2, dotsize=0.5) + coord_flip()`
```

Which generates this graph:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqpnZ.png)

I'm trying to create a similar graph using highcharter, but I don't know the syntax for stacking a dotplot in it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:
Code to generate my data:

```
sample(2016:2023,40,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL)
sample(2016:2023,40,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL) -> yearValue
sample(1:12,40,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL) -> monthValue
sample(1:28,40,replace = TRUE,prob = NULL) -> dayValue
((dayValue-1)/30) + ((monthValue-1)/12)+(yearValue) -> yearValueDecimal`
```

Data Output:

```
structure(list(yearValueDecimal = c(2022.21666666667, 2022.83333333333, 
2016.98333333333, 2021.43333333333, 2023.7, 2022.03333333333, 
2022.86666666667, 2022.46666666667, 2020.81666666667, 2020.1, 
2022.31666666667, 2023.93333333333, 2016.48333333333, 2016.83333333333, 
2018.81666666667, 2017.4, 2019.5, 2017.43333333333, 2019.58333333333, 
2019.7, 2022.3, 2020.25, 2023.41666666667, 2019.35, 2019.11666666667, 
2017.73333333333, 2019.78333333333, 2019.33333333333, 2022.86666666667, 
2020.25, 2021.26666666667, 2016.56666666667, 2016.53333333333, 
2023.83333333333, 2022.56666666667, 2021.85, 2018.3, 2022.66666666667, 
2019.68333333333, 2019.95)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = 
c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001b0dadf3320>)
```

Current highcharter code:

```
dt%>%
hchart(type = 'scatter', hcaes(x = 1, y = 'yearValueDecimal'))%>%
hc_plotOptions(stacking = "normal")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBnEO.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a highcharts dot plot graph? - R Highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262294/how-to-create-a-highcharts-dot-plot-graph-r-highcharter)

Comment: @nrennie It doesn't, unfortunately. I know how to create a basic dotplot, my issue is figuring out how to have points in the same/similar bins stack instead of clumping on top of one another.

Comment: Can you share your code for the highcharter plot that you've already tried? Ideally also share a sample of data using `dput()` - it makes it much easier for others to help if we can run your code. If you also read the answers to the question above, you'll see that this type of chart isn't really built-in to highcharter so there may not be an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with {highcharter}, but I don't think dot plots are a built-in feature so the easiest way is to essentially build a scatter plot. One way to do this is to bin the year data, count how many values are in that bin, and then create the coordinates of points from that:

```r
# count number of obs per bin (change breaks for more/less bins)
binned_dt <- dt |> 
  mutate(bin_years = cut(yearValueDecimal, breaks = 20)) |> 
  group_by(bin_years) |> 
  summarise(num = n())

# make coordinates for y value of scatter plot
plot_data <- binned_dt |> 
  uncount(num) |> 
  group_by(bin_years) |> 
  mutate(y = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup()

# plot
library(highcharter)
plot_data %>%
  hchart(type = 'scatter', hcaes(x = 'bin_years', y = 'y'))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(stacking = "normal")
```

this gives:

[image]

You could then look at changing the labels on the x-axis (either before or after you plot the data using highcharter).